# Position a button on the right of each row with overflow-x

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to add a button next to each row of my table. Plot twist, the table is inside a div with a fixed width and overflow-x for responsiveness. I want the button to show next to each row outside the container div.

With my current code, the button does show up next to the row but stays in the fixed div.

```html
<div style="width:100px; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
        <td>
          <div style="position:relative; width:0px;">
            <button style="position:absolute;left:10px;">Edit</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: regarding your problematic, you can't do it at my point of view without nesting this div and the button inside a parent container. Because if overflow-x is set to scroll, nothing will go outside the scroll at right.

Comment: Just avoid position absolute in tables and leave button in plain td tag. Add white bg color to last cells in tables. Keep it simple when possible.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll have to create a seperated container for the buttons then. I wanted to avoid this. to make sure that the height would always match. Or I settle with have the user to always scroll to get to the controls.

Comment: you'll probably need some sort of plugin - I usually use datatables: https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html

Comment: @pete I used datatables in the past. Didn't know they had an option. Thanks. That lead me to the answer. I need to add style="position: sticky; right: 0px" to the last column. See https://jsfiddle.net/LouisOuellet/uLm43gjt/2/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using position sticky on the last column.

```
position: sticky; right: 0px
```

Reference : [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp).

Here's the snippet:

```html
<div style="width:100px; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th><th>ID</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
        <td style="position: sticky; right: 0px">
          <button>Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```